# Using DataTriggers in XAML to force events on CheckBox property changing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, datatrigger

I have a CheckBox set up something like this:

```
<CheckBox Unchecked="checkBox_Unchecked">
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyVal}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

Is there any way to get the Unchecked event to fire when my Setter sets IsChecked = False?

Comment: When IsChecked of Checkbox is False, the UnChecked event should raise. That is the default behavior.

Comment: The weird thing is, it seems to be in one case and not in another case. I guess I should specify that by "force" I mean just make it more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a procedural approach; But for your statement, **I guess I should specify that by "force"...** You can make this using this work around;

1) In your ViewModel have a boolean property listening to 'INotifyPropertyChanged'

2) Let the default value of property be true;

3) In your constructor re-assign the property's value to 'false'.

4) This will trigger the unchecked event;

XAML:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding CheckboxChecked}" Unchecked="ToggleButton_OnUnchecked"/>
```

C#:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool m_CheckboxChecked = true;

        public bool CheckboxChecked
        {
            get { return m_CheckboxChecked; }
            set { m_CheckboxChecked = value; OnPropertyChanged("CheckboxChecked"); }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
            CheckboxChecked = false;
        }

        private void ToggleButton_OnUnchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Un-Checked");
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a Setter for the Case `IsChecked = false` too. Also I would recommend to bind to a Command in the `ViewModel` Try this:

```
            <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ElementName=this, Path=DataContext.ItemCheckedCommand}"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ElementName=this, Path=DataContext.ItemCheckedCommand}"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
```

And define a command where you have your logic in the VM:

```
public RelayCommand ItemCheckCommand {get; private set;}
```